# Access to the path is denied when trying to build ASP.Net core VS2015 project

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

I have an ASP.NET Core RTM application that I copied and checked into TFS from Visual Studio.d. However when I do build it I get the following error

> Failed to make the following project runnable: MyApplication (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2) reason: Access to the path 'C:\Source\MyApplication\MyApplication\b\bin\Debug\net452\win7-x64\MyApplication.exe.config' is denied.    Mars.Web    C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DotNet\Microsoft.DotNet.Common.Targets  262

What I have tried but isn't working

- run Visual Studio 2015 as Administrator
- Remove the readonly property or set permissions to all for the `bin\Debug\net452\win7-x64\` directory
- Deleting thr `bin` Directory
- Restart Visual Studio and make sure I am connected to TFS
- Run `dotnet restore` in my project root directory as mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38328677/failed-to-make-the-following-project-runnable-object-reference-not-set-to-an-in) answer
- Delete `obj` and `bin` directory

Answer (score 3):

I deleted my `app.config` as well as `bin` directory

Comment: Worked for me .