# Failed to make the following project runnable

Tags: asp.net, mongodb, asp.net-core, identityserver4

I know its a duplicate question, but I am unable to solve my problem.

I make a project using mongoDb and asp.net core. But when I run my project below error showing. **I restore dotnet but still its showing Error**.

**Failed to make the following project runnable: AuthMongoDB (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0) reason: Expected coreclr library not found in package graph. Please try running dotnet restore again.**

N.B : I make one costume library named "IdentityServer4.MongoDB".

I found below solution but none of those solution is working for me.

**[Failed to make the following project runnable (Object reference not set to an instance of an object.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38328677/failed-to-make-the-following-project-runnable-object-reference-not-set-to-an-in)**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Delete `project.lock.json` from project folder and then try `dotnet restore`.

Comment: @Sanket, Thanks bro, but its not working :(